# Change gradle project directory, cannot use eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I have a gradle project I had imported into eclipse (it is the [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation.html) sample project "*The Plane that couldn't fly good*" [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Running-Demos)), and it runs fine.

Now I exited eclipse, moved the project directory elsewere, re-launched eclipse, and it complains it can not find the project files (fine, I moved them in other directory).

So I am trying to open the project from the new directory but I am unable to find a file to feed eclipse with (such as a .sln file for visual studio); I tried to re-import the project, but eclipse complains:

> trunk.theplanethatcouldntflygood-android existing workspace project
>   theplanethatcouldntflygood-android has the same name

So I am wondering if I am trying an impossible use case (*NEVER* change a gradle project directory) or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the old project in Eclipse first and then import it again.